# Make a vector space into a module on ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

I'm teaching myself about modules and I came across this exercise that I'm having trouble with (found here: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter4.pdf).

The question asks: Let $T$ be a linear transformation on the vector space $V$ over the field $F$. Show how to make $V$ into an $R$-module in a natural way, where $R$ is the polynomial ring $F[x]$.

My inclination was to say that for a polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...a_0x^0$, and a vector $v, f(x)*v=f(v)$ where $v^n=T^n(v)$ and $T^0(v)=v$. Essentially, scalar multiplication here is evaluation of the polynomial with $v$, but using our given linear transformation in place of exponentiation. That the unity works here as before is obvious (if $f(x)=1, f(v)=v$). Distributivity (of both forms) should follow from linearity of $T$. Associativity of scalar multiplication follows from the fact that $ax^n*bx^m=abx^{n+m}$ and $aT^n(x)*bT^m(x)=abT^{n+m}(x)$. Without going through a rigorous proof, can someone verify that my idea is right?

Comment: Yes, this works. It's a nice exercise to check that that such a $R$-module is never free, unless $V$ is the trivial vector space.

Comment: Of course, the statement in my comment about $V$ not being free as a $R$-module is only true when $V$ is finite dimensional over $F$.

Comment: Note that for any $f = a_n x^n + \dots + a_0 \in F[x]$ we can evaluate $f$ at $T$ to obtain a linear transformation $f(T) = a_n T^n + \dots + a_0 \text{id}_V$. The module structure you defined is then given by letting $f$ act on $v$ as $f(T)$, i.e. $f * v = f(T)(v)$. I believe this to be a slightly more standard notation. In any way, what you did is correct.